# Getting error when importing a react component: required is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I have a `TodoItem` component and wants to import it in other component, this is the way i am importing:

```
import TodoItem from 'TodoItem';
```

what is wrong in this import line, it is throwing the error:

> required is not defined

These are the components:

```
class LayOut extends React.Component{

constructor(){
    super();
    this.changeStatus = this.changeStatus.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        tasks:[
            {
                name:"buy milk",
                completed: false
            },
            {
                name:"buy water",
                completed: false
            },
            {
                name:"buy yougard",
                completed: false
            }
        ]
    }
}
changeStatus(index){
    var tasks = this.state.tasks;
    var task = tasks[index];
    task.completed = !task.completed;
    this.setState({tasks:tasks})
}
render(){
    return(
            <ul>
                {
                    this.state.tasks.map((task, index)=> {
                        return <TodoItem clickHandler={this.changeStatus} index={index} key={task.name} detail={task} />
                    })
                }
            </ul>
    );
}
}

var app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(<LayOut />, app);
```

This is the file that i want to export:

```
class TodoItem extends React.Component{

  render(){
      return(
          <li onClick={ ()=>{this.props.clickHandler(this.props.index); }} className={this.props.detail.completed ? 'completed' : ''}>
            {this.props.detail.name}
          </li>
      );
  }
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `import TodoItem from './TodoItem'; //path to TodoItem`

**Reason**: when you use `import TodoItem from 'TodoItem'`, `TodoItem` will be treated as node modules, not a custom defined component. To correctly import the custom component we need to provide the path. use `./` if it exist in same directory, otherwise use `../` to provide the path.

Comment: can you show your folder structure where these 2 files exist ?

Comment: i have one component folder in which two file one is Layout.js and other is TodoItem.js

Comment: in that case `import TodoItem from './TodoItem';` it will work, i think cause of the error is something else, check the console

Comment: i have try that but its not working i think there is a problem behind settings is any settings required for react webpack etc ?

Comment: even when i am import React from "react"; then geting the same error i don,t know why